# What does `:build-operation "program-op"` do for ABCL?

Tags: common-lisp, asdf, abcl

From SBCL, CLISP and ECL you can pass the `:build-operation "program-op"` argument to the `(asdf:defsystem ...)` to generate a stand-alone binary. What does ABCL do when you set that option? I can't find any output files, is it just plain unsupported?

[ASDF documentation on `program-op`](https://asdf.common-lisp.dev/asdf.html#index-program_002dop)

I've found various articles about how to generate a stand-alone executable using ABCL, but I'm curious about why I don't see any effects from the actual ASDF standard way of doing so.

Comment: I think that this should work for ABCL since it is one of the supported implementations. You should add information about which versions of ABCL and ASDF you are using. How did you invoke `program-op`? You should include that, too. Did you follow the [example code provided by ASDF?](https://github.com/fare/asdf/blob/master/test/hello-world-example.asd) Note that you can't build binaries from the Slime repl; you will probably have to go into the ABCL repl to build a binary.

Comment: Thanks @adabsurdum I had a mistake in my build script which hid an error. I've opened a ticket upstream and will post an answer here once I've got it.